# GCMParameterSpec throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: unknown parameter type

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm

I am doing android data encryption to save in SharedPreferences. GCMParameterSpec was introduced in Android in API 19 which I'm using for `AES/GCM/NoPadding` encryption. This is how I'm implementing it:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(context),new GCMParameterSpec(128,Base64.decode(myGeneratedIV, Base64.DEFAULT)));
```

My problem is, in Android 4.4.2 (API 19) I get the error mentioned thrown, but from API 21 it works.

About the exception, from the Android docs:

> if the given algorithm parameters are inappropriate for this cipher, or this cipher requires algorithm parameters and params is null, or the given algorithm parameters imply a cryptographic strength that would exceed the legal limits (as determined from the configured jurisdiction policy files).

My question is: Is there a specific reason for this behaviour? Why doesn't the `init` method from Cipher identify the params?

I even tried encrypting without giving a specific IV:

```
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(context));
```

And once I tried to decrypt the same way:

```
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(context));
```

It throws the same exception(InvalidAlgorithmParameterException) saying a `GCMParameterSpec` is needed for decryption.

I tried giving the `GCMParameterSpec` only to the decryption, and I get the unknown parameter type exception.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @MaartenBodewes. I ended up defining a different encryption mode for API 19. I looked up for a viable and secure way of encryption besides GCM that also uses IV and I chose to use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding".

Comment: I used IvParamaterSpec with the AES/GCM/NoPadding and it worked. Thank you

Comment: As the Cipher's instance is AES/GCM I though I had to use GCMParameterSpec, the main reason why I never even tried using IvParamaterSpec. Worked perfectly and I was able to avoid using AES/CBC

Comment: For anyone arriving here, I managed to solve the same problem by updating the security Provider using `ProviderInstaller` https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider?hl=en#patching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that the `CipherSpi` implementation within the provider in Android may not support `GCMParameterSpec` yet. Defining an API is not the same thing as providing support for it within the underlying cryptography provider.

Instead you can use the standard `IvParameterSpec` provided for the other modes as well. Simply use the (12) IV/nonce bytes for your `GCMParamterSpec` directly as your IV.

As you have the standard tag size this should pose no problem with your implementation.

---

In case the tag size differs then the solution becomes more complicated as verification will only use the leftmost bytes of the resulting tag. Unfortunately the tag generation and verification is hidden within the API design of the `Cipher` class.

Answer (score 4):

As @Maarten says, you can use `IvParameterSpec` for devices running KitKat:

```
private static final int TAG_LENGTH_BYTES = 16;

public byte[] encrypt(...) {
    ...
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(rawEncryptionKey, "AES"), getParams(iv));
    ...
}

public byte[] decrypt(...) {
    ...
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(rawEncryptionKey, "AES"), getParams(iv));
    ...
}

private static AlgorithmParameterSpec getParams(final byte[] iv) {
    return getParams(iv, 0, iv.length);
}

private static AlgorithmParameterSpec getParams(final byte[] buf, int offset, int len) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // GCMParameterSpec should always be present in Java 7 or newer, but it's missing on
        // some Android devices with API level <= 19. Fortunately, we can initialize the cipher
        // with just an IvParameterSpec. It will use a tag size of 128 bits.
        return new IvParameterSpec(buf, offset, len);
    }
    return new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BYTES * 8, buf, offset, len);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this code ...

```
    private static final String Key = "0123456789abcdef";

public static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new SecretKeySpec(Key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
}

public static byte[] encryptMsg(String message, SecretKey secret)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidParameterSpecException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Cipher cipher;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}

public static String decryptMsg(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey secret)
        throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Cipher cipher;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: I need to meet security requirements so changing the Cipher instance is not an option. For further information, "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" has a lot of security issues, the main reason why you should not use it for data encryption

Comment: There are a lot of bad crypto code fragments out there and this is -unfortunately- one of them. In general, please do not paste generic encryption/decryption code in response to a specific answer. Note also that code fragments *in themselves* are not considered answers on StackOverflow: you need to explain *how* and *why* they solve the problem in the question. Thanks for trying though, please don't let this detain you from posting other answers.